# one application registered with two ICON on IPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, launch

Our customer has a particular request for my project.
how to use short-cut to launch our application?
what I am trying to do is create an standalone application does nothing except to launch my main application to skip some step go to more depth level?

maybe one application is registered with two icons, one is for main process, one is to do short-cut process.

is that possible?

I have searched this site, someone mentioned to create an application to launch another application? is there an example or a piece of code?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably technically feasible with a [custom url schemes](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html), but I doubt that Apple would approve the "shortcut" app for release in the App store.